# Capybara have_field not finding field found by have_selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm currently writing a Cucumber feature for a messaging system in a Rails app. This is one of my steps.

```
Then(/^they should see the message displayed in their language$/) do
  id = "message_to_#{@family.id}"
  expect(page).to have_selector("textarea##{id}")
  save_and_open_page
  expect(page).to have_field(id, type: :textarea)
end
```

The first assertion passes, but the second fails. When I inspect the markup created by save_and_open_page, the following element is present:

```
<textarea cols="22" disabled="disabled" id="message_to_13" name="body" placeholder="Hallo, Ich bin sehr interessiert an deinem Profil. Würdest du gerne mit mir in Kontakt treten?" rows="7"></textarea>
```

The error message displayed for the second test is:

```
expected to find field "message_to_13" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters. (Capybara::ExpectationNotMet)
```

I'm tearing my hair out here to understand why Capybara can find this element that is obviously present using have_selector, but not with have_field?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that the textarea has the `disabled="disabled"` attribute, meaning it is a disabled field. By default, Capybara ignores disabled fields. New in Capybara 2.1 is the option to [look for disabled fields](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/982).

Adding the `disabled: true` option will solve your problem:

```
expect(page).to have_field(id, type: 'textarea', disabled: true)
```

Note:

- That when you include `disabled: true`, the field must be disabled. The default is `disabled: false`, which only matches fields that are not disabled.
- That the :type value should be a string. As seen in the above, it is `type: 'textarea')`. Using a symbol, `type: :textarea` will not work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I see this behaviour is described in the Capybara 2.1 release notes, but is it mentioned anywhere in the official docs?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the fix updated the code, but did not update any of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, that you have some other element with either id, name or label that matches 'message_to_13'?

Because that's what the error message indicates - that it found something with 'message_to_13' but it wasn't a textarea. You could also try passing :textarea as string not symbol.

Comment: The id of textarea in question is the only part of the document where the string 'message_to_13' occurs. I've tried passing the :textarea as a string, and not at all, and still receive the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is looking for an input field of type textarea.  Textareas are not input fields, they are textareas.  Try dropping the `type: :textarea`.

See here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/978

Comment: "Note: 'textarea' and 'select' are valid type names, matching the associated tag names."

http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/2.1.0/frames

Comment: Which version of capybara are you using?  Supporting textarea as a type seems to have come in at version 2.1.0.  The link I posted above is for version 2.0.2.  Sorry, I didn't realise until now that had changed.

Comment: I'm using version 2.1.0

Comment: Weird indeed.  Did you try 'textarea' instead of :textarea?

Comment: Yes. I've also tried dropping the :type option completely. All give the exact same results.

Comment: The documentation is slightly misleading. If the value is 'textarea' or 'select', the node name will get checked rather than the type attribute (https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L108).